# how can i make field dependent to another field in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

```
<td>Branch</td>
 <td>
 <select name="branch" type="text">                            
    <option value="0">Select Branch</option>
    <option value="CE">CE</option>
    <option value="IT">IT</option>
 </td>
<td>Batch</td>
```

i.e if i have branch field in my jsp form
so my branch firld contains 2 inputs as 1.CE & 2.IT.
So when i click on CE ,so it have to show me A1,A2,....A5 & when i click on IT, it will have to show B1...B5 from which  we can select any one of the field.
So, pls help me for above program.
Here is my code.
Pls help me what code should i write in "Batch" field""

Comment: what framework you use..??

Answer (score 0):

you have to register onChange() event of the branch and call an javascript function which will populate the batch field accordingly.